# HERE SDK Flutter : Smooth Camera + remove 3D building

Tags: flutter, here-api

We use **heresdk-4.5.3.0-release** for **Flutter** edition Navigate.

While a "Navigation", the map camera moves jerkily, it's not smooth like your official app on the "Here WeGo" Store.

As indicated in your documentation, we use "LocationEngine" to retrieve the position of the phone, and we inject a "VisualNavigator" in the "addLocationListener" function.

then, we have this kind of function to update the map (function found in your examples) :

```
  // Update location and rotation of map. Update location of arrow.
  void _updateMapView(HERE.GeoCoordinates currentGeoCoordinates, double bearingInDegrees) {
    HERE.MapCameraOrientationUpdate orientation = HERE.MapCameraOrientationUpdate.withDefaults();
    orientation.bearing = bearingInDegrees;
    orientation.tilt = 180.0;
    _hereMapController.camera.lookAtPointWithOrientationAndDistance(
      currentGeoCoordinates,
      orientation,
      100,
    );
    _navigationArrow.coordinates = currentGeoCoordinates;
  }
```

How can we have a smooth camera movement?

We are unable to remove the 3D buildings on the default map, how can we get a 2D map only. Thank you

**UPDATE**

About my concern with the fluidity of the camera, I tested to use directly this method "startRendering" in the class "VisualNavigator":

https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.5.1.0/api_reference/navigation/VisualNavigator/startRendering.html

With this implementation I can have a smooth navigation experience, however, I can't change the image of the "location marker" :(

Comment: Which edition are you using (explore or navigate)?

Comment: Navigate edition

Comment: Welcome to SO, Pem. Just a note: It's normally better not to put two different questions into one, since you get partials answers.

Comment: You are right, sorry

Comment: Just to confirm, you are totally right, when you call startRendering(), the map will be smoothly interpolated. But it will also render a position marker. This is something I would expect to be customizable in the future. Right now it is not possible. Unless: If you use the _updateMapView() you pasted above and don't call start rendering, the map will be updated in discrete steps, for each new position that arrives on device. You can fully customize this on your own, eg, you can use TickerProvider and Tween class (both from Flutter) to interpolate smoothly between two coordinates.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this information. I will keep the logic with "startRendering" and waiting to have a solution from Here SDK to change the image of my location marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable extruded buildings, use the setLayerState (https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/4.5.1.0/api_reference/mapview/MapScene/setLayerState.html) from your MapView instance and set LayerState "hidded" for value MapScenLayers.extrudedBuildings (https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/4.5.1.0/api_reference/mapview/MapSceneLayers/extrudedBuildings.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you run `flutter build [apk/ios] --release` and then install the app, it usually runs a lot smoother than a debug build.